# Getting command line argument that stores in a variable

Tags: bash, command-line

I am writing a bash script to finger the first three line of user's info.

ex:

```
$ ./c.sh bob unknown
Login: bob                           Name: Bob
Directory: /u1/h7/bob                Shell: /bin/tcsh
Office: AA 044, x8361                   Home Phone: 000-000-0000

unknown: no such user.
```

Here is my code so far

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# == 0 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./c.sh Login/Username"
  exit
else
  i=$#
  j=1
  while [ "$j" -le "$i" ]; do
    finger ${$j} | head -n+3
    echo
    j=$(($j+1))
  done
fi
```

instead of giving what user types for the command line arguments, ${$j} is giving me the the value of $j, any suggestion and help for how to get the login/username? I've tried $($j), $((j)), ${$j}....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer: stop using unnecessary indirection:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( $# == 0 )); then
  echo "Usage: ./c.sh Login/Username"
  exit
else
  while [[ $1 ]]; do
    finger "$1" | head -n+3
    echo
    shift
  done
fi
```

or…

```
…
for user; do # equivalent to `for user in "$@"; do`
  finger "$user" | head -n+3
  …
done
```

You *could* write it this way:

```
i=$#
j=1
while [ $j -le $i ]; do
  finger "${@:j++:1}" | head -n+3
  echo
done
```

…but you don't need to work that hard.

Comment: Just use `for user; do` to iterate over the script arguments.

Comment: @EtanReisner matter of style. There's nothing wrong with `while [[ $1 ]] … shift` IMO

Comment: Other than only being able to loop over the arguments once and requiring extra processing to shift the entries down (as trivial as that effort may be), no there's nothing wrong with it. It just doesn't give you any benefits either since you don't even get the benefit of current argument count from that loop (that you would from the manual `++` counting version).

Comment: @EtanReisner but all of the things you mention are things that are not needed in this program. There are cases where the `shift` version is better suited over the `for` loop version, too. In this case, it just doesn't matter.

Comment: That doesn't make it a matter of style though. And yes, there are times when `shift` is exactly what you want, this isn't one of them as far as I'm concerned but ultimately this is bike-shedding at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 Login/Username"
    exit
else
    for ARG in "$@"; do
        finger "$ARG" | head -n 3
        echo # If you want a newline
    done
fi
```

As simple as it can be.